# when use order by i get "Divide by zero error encountered."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Query which works if I remove the last line which is order by.
Can anyone tell me please why this is not working when I put order by on this query.

```
declare @UQ as decimal(20,6); 
declare @MUQ as decimal(20,6); 

select @UQ=ItemUnit_UnitQuantity, @MUQ=ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity from tItemUnit 
where ItemUnit_Id = 23996
select top 1 (InvBuyPriceValue/InvL_Quantity)*iu.ItemUnit_UnitQuantity/iu.ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity*@MUQ/@UQ  as InvBuyPrice, Discount
from tInvL l 
left outer join tInvH h on h.InvH_Id = l.InvH_Id 
left outer join tItem i on i.Item_Id = l.Item_Id 
left outer join tItemUnit iu on iu.ItemUnit_Id = l.ItemUnit_Id 
left outer join tUnit u on u.Unit_Id = iu.Unit_Id
left outer join tClientObj clo on clo.ClientObj_Id = h.ClientObj_Id 
left outer join tDocType dt on dt.DocType_Id = h.DocType_Id 
where h.CompanyObj_Id = (select CompanyObj_Id from tEnabledCompany where CompanyClientObj_Id=(select ClientObj_Id from tClientObj where ClientObj_Code = '504'))
and dt.DocType_InOut = 1
and l.Item_Id = 19558
and h.ClientObj_Id = 386
order by InvH_DocDate desc, InvH_DocTime desc
```

I get the error saying:
**Divide by zero error encountered.**

I don't understand why I get this error on order by and not for example in select statement...

Comment: (InvBuyPriceValue/InvL_Quantity) check this values before divide it with the order by. You should see what it's happening.

Comment: Because without the order by, it can just take the first row it computes for the result set and (presumably) that row, by chance, contains non-zero `InvL_Quantity` and `iu.ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity` values. But when you add the `ORDER BY`, more rows have to be produced and one or more of those contains a zero value for one or both of the above values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are divisions in

```
select top 1 (InvBuyPriceValue/InvL_Quantity)*iu.ItemUnit_UnitQuantity/iu.ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity*@MUQ/@UQ
```

so probably InvL_Quantity or iu.ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity are zero.

Why don't you see the SQL Server error without the ORDER BY? You are only requesting the TOP 1 row, so the SQL Server does not need to go over all rows and calculate the result. For performance reasons the SQL Server just picks the TOP 1 row, calculates the results for it and returns it.

That you get a divide-by-zero with TOP 1 and not without is just by chance. You'll definitely see the same error if you don't TOP 1 and if you don't ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    (InvBuyPriceValue / InvL_Quantity) * 
     iu.ItemUnit_UnitQuantity / iu.ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity * 
     @MUQ / @UQ AS InvBuyPrice,
```

That is the only place where you are performing divisions. Either `InvL_Quantity` or `ItemUnit_MainUnitQuantity` columns might contain the value zero.

Also check `ItemUnit_UnitQuantity`, which is the value being assigned to `@UQ`, which is also a divisor.